# Search function with a FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

for my application I use a Realtime Database from Firebase, and I display its content using a FirebaseAnimatedList widget. I want to search inside of that list, and I thought I could do that by changing the query at runtime, but for some reason that doesn't work...

Can somebody help me out with some code for a FirebaseAnimatedList with a search function?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: But note that queries are immutable: they can't be changed after you create them. So for a new search, you will need to create a new query, and attach the results of that query to your list widget.

Comment: Well I'm not seeking for debugging help, since i can't think of any code solving this problem, thats why I'm asking here.